# Unable to attach large database to SQL Server engine run in docker container process

Tags: sql-server, docker, large-data, docker-image

I use SQL Server 2019 image `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest` from [hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) to create process by this command:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=xxx" -p 1433:1433 --name sql -h sql -v d:/data:/var/opt/mssql/data/ mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

SSMS connects to SQL Server service on port 1433 successfully and even I can create new database or attach a `*.mdf` file (one of my attached db is 40GB) from selected volume. But in SQL Server attach dialog, I can't see my main database (with 140GB size) file. Even in **All Files(*)** mode. I remember many years ago, see same problem when we wanted to attach `*.mdf` file created with older version of SQL Server in a newer version.

**EDITED**

In fact my experiences is about attach created db with old version (maybe SQL Server 2014) in new version(maybe SQL Server 2017) in installed instance in pc. I remember that those files don't listed in file selector dialog box for attach database. but in this case, database created with sql2019 engine and so compatibility exist.

I don't want to import database in to image an do some things like that.I want access to external database file and only use of docker process as temporary SQL Server engine host.

Can anybody help me to know why this problem happen and how can I solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: *"but in sqlServer attach dialog, i can't see my main Database (with 140GB size) file. "* what does this mean? You say you saw this "many years ago" but only SQL Server 2017 and 2019 have been supported in a docker environment; both are recent releases.

Comment: @Larun, i don't said same problem happened in docker. in fact my experiences is about attach created db with old version (maybe sql2014) in new version(maybe sql 2017)  not in sql docker container but in inestalled instance in pc. I remember that those files don't listed in file selector dialog box for attach database.**post edited for remove ambiguity**

Comment: What happens if you write the T-SQL to attach the database instead of relying on the GUI?

Comment: I used `CREATE DATABASE` command with existing file path as `FILENAME` but get error `Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101 - Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)"`
but this command executed successfuly for some other mdf file. it's amazing.

Comment: That would suggest, therefore, that the instance does *not* have access to the file, if you say it really does exist. You'll need to check the permissions in the directory and of the file.

Comment: I think permission is not problem,because other `MDF` file in that directory is accessible and usable without any manual settings. The problem must be some things about `Ubuntu` (OS of docker image),I think. But I don't know why this problem happen and how can I solve this.

Comment: As a regular daily driver of Ubuntu, and containers (though LXC), I doubt this. I've had a copy of the Stack Overflow Database (well in excess of 300GB) attach fine on SQL Server on Linux (running in LXC). If you can't see the file from the container, there the problem isn't related to SQL Server; if you can, then it's a permissions issue within the docker envronement

Answer (score 0):

By Thanks of [Larno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) for contribution, my problem solved with check and edit permission for access to `MDF` file. In fact, Size of `MDF` file isn't Problem.

Thanks again.